# portal password reset page

Tags: portal

We have a customer portal (yes, I'm aware communities is the new thing - but we are not migrating to communities for several reasons). Some time ago, when another administrator original went through an implemented it, set up a log in page on our own domain for the customer portal - I noticed recently it wasn't comprehensive and only masked the log in page, but used SF's default reset password pages. I'm trying this as a concept before I get our web admins to update our pages, so there's 3 pages currently involved: Login.html, PasswordReset.html, and PasswordResetConfirm.html. The override on the log in page works and I'm able to reset the password from a custom page. What I'm having trouble with is overriding the confirmation of the reset password:

[image]

Here's what I've got for the form on the PasswordReset.html, but it does not appear to be working. I've tried adding a "saveURL", but it seems that it will prepend "https://na19.salesforce.com/" in every case. Is there any way to change where the page redirects to for the confirmation?

```
<form  style="margin-left: 320px; margin-top: 20px;" action="https://na19.salesforce.com/secur/forgotpasswordp.jsp" id="editPage" method="post" name="editPage" onsubmit="if (window.ffInAlert) { return false; }" >
<input type="hidden" name="cancelURL" id="cancelURL" value="Login.html" />                      
<input type="hidden" name="orgId" id="orgId" value="00D300000000Q4e" />
<input type="hidden" name="portalId" id="portalId" value="06030000000cXQh" />
<input type="hidden" name="retURL" id="retURL0" value="Login.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="retURL" id="retURL1" value="PasswordResetConfirm.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="save_new_url" id="save_new_url" value="https://na19.salesforce.com/secur/forgotpasswordp.jsp?retURL=PasswordResetConfirm.html&amp;orgId=00D300000000Q4e&amp;portalId=06030000000cXQh" />
```

I found a few similar questions, but they were in regards to communities and I'm not sure 'chatter answers' will solve this issue when we want to use our domain instead of salesforce's.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is happening, but it is possible to redirect to your domain page.

Salesforce has a Reset Password method which can be used and after reset, you can return your own page reference.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_resetPassword

In your current example, you are submitting a form to change the password. That's why you don't have any control over reset. Instead of that use a simple VF page and use controller to reset the password.

To support custom domain:

1. Setup a HTML page with all information
2. Consume SF standard API to change password (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_resetpassword.htm)
3. You can also setup a custom API to fulfill additional actions

Comment: Is there an alternative to using a VF page to achieve this? The form looks like it's using javascript to submit, so I imagine it would just have to be a parameter change?

As I mentioned, the current log in page is an HTML page hosted on our company's domain, not SFDC's - so I don't think I can use the system class from an HTML page.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include support for custom domain.

Comment: Thanks - I went ahead and started with using SF's AJAX API and have had _some_ luck.

At first I was getting an error about cross origin requests were only supported for http, data, chrome, etc (because I was running it locally). So I put it up on our tomcat server (used for another project) and then started getting issues where the AJAX isn't connecting correctly because I guess tomcat is acting as a proxy. I don't know all the details for the proxy and I doubt I'd be able to get it from our admins. 

Do you have a recommended way to go about testing this? This is new territory for me.

Comment: Great. Glad that it helped. Can you mark the best answer and upvote? It will help others to find out a solution. Also if you can post your solution as well if possible at all.

Comment: No solution yet - hit enter too soon D: